# Keras: multiclass classification Dense layer

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I've seen that we can use `Dense(num_classes, ...)` as the output layer, but I've also seen `Dense((num_classes-1), ...)` especially when talking about binary classification. Which do you use and why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2-cent,

I use Dense(num_classes) because I can compute softmax on the output of this layer.

For a binary classification, we typically use cross-entropy as a loss function. Thus, we only need to compute p(x = 1) and p(x = 0) can be computed as 1 - p(x=1).

For a multiclass classification, the only advantage to reduce the size of output by 1 is to reduce the number parameters because we can compute p(x = k) = 1 - sum_{i=1}^K p(x=i), given that K is the number classes. So if you plan not to use softmax but a different function, maybe you can have the output layer to have (num_classes - 1) units.

Comment: Hi @unaki, thanks for the reply. Binary classification as you say can be done with one output unit because P(class 1) = 1 - P(class 0). But also as you say, the linear dependency exists with multiple classes. So theoretically you shouldn't need `Dense(num_classes)` - that should be redundant. `Dense(num_classes - 1)` should suffice. Why doesn't it?

Comment: I see. In most cases, we want to normalize the output layer so that its sum will be 1. One common function is softmax. However, the framework like tensorflow, its softmax function takes a vector of the size (num_classes). That is why we have to keep the number of dimensions as the number of classes. So in sum, we do this due to implementation constraint.